# best way to call function from an extended class

Tags: php, class, phpstorm, extends

I am using `phpstorm` as IDE. And in my `class.php`, I started the class as

```
class MyClass extends Database{
    function sample(){
        $this->query();
    }
}
```

the `query()` is in the class `Database`. But phpstorm shows a warning that

```
Method 'query' not found in class MyClass. Referenced method is not found in subject class.
```

But the function is working without any problem.

Is there any problem with this code style? Or Do I need to try a different approach? I searched many websites. But didn't get a proper answer. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Is this the actual piece of code that shows the error?

Comment: Sorry for that missing of information. That code is working perfectly. I edited that in code now. :)

Comment: $this->query(); should be inside of a method.

Comment: Without screenshots / proper code we will not be able to help you. Because right now it looks like you do not know how PHP works (based on code sample you have provided).

Comment: @MarvinSaldinger, yeah. sorry for thet. Missed to add that. But in my actual code, it is with in a method. and is shows the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need everything in classes to be called from a method or outside of the class after the class is instantiated.

you cannot use `$this` outside the method scope in a class

EDIT, OP changed question :

works fine for me, no warning
[image]

Comment: It is not an error. Just a warning by PHPStorm. If I hover on `query()`, it shows the message

Comment: Try to invalidate your cache and restart phpstorm, it might be a caching/index problem

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass extends Database{
   function sample(){
       parent::query();
   }
}
```

Is this working?

Comment: now the warning is the previous error in the question, and it shows one more warning `Multiple definitions exist for class parent`

Comment: @Arun Which means that you have multiple (more than one) `Database` classes in your project

Comment: How it could be possible? multiple class with name name will cause error while execution. Right? Here no such things happened

Comment: @Arun *"How it could be possible?"* Check your project -- how do I know how did you set it up and what libraries you are using? *"multiple class with name name will cause error while execution. Right?"* Only if you import both of them. Otherwise no. But from IDE point of view it does not know which class to use.