# Method not found in class

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

I'm working on a login function but got an error that I can't figure out.

This is my Model Login class:

```
class Login {

    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $cxn;       //database object

    function __construct($username,$password)
    {
        //set data
        $this->setData($username, $password);
        //connect DB
        $this->connectToDB();
        // get Data 
    }

    function setData($username, $password)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    private function connectToDB()
    {
        include 'Database.php';
        $connect = '../include/connect.php';
        $this->cxn = new database($connect);  
    }

    function getData()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM anvandare WHERE anvandarnamn = '$this->username' AND losenord ='$this->'password'";
        $sql = mysql_query($query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Användarnamnet eller Lösenordet är fel. Försök igen.");
        } 
    }

    function close() 
    {
        $this->cxn->close(); //Here is the error it says "Method 'close' not found in class
    }
}
```

The last function gives error "*Method 'close' not found in class*", "*Referenced method is not found in subject class.*"

Here is my Database class:

```
class Database {

    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;                  
    private $database;

   function __construct($filename)
   {       
       if(is_file($filename)) include $filename;
       else throw new exception("Error!");

       $this->host=$host;
       $this->user=$user;
       $this->password=$password;
       $this->database=$database;

       $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        //Connect to the server
        if(!mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password))
        throw new exception("Error, not connected to the server.");

        //Select the database
        if(!mysql_select_db($this->database))
        throw new exception("Error, no database selected");             
    }

    function close()
    {
        mysql_close();
    }
}
```

The pathways are correct so it's not it. What could be the error?

Comment: Please stop using the outdated `mysql_*` function and learn how to use PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: It is hard for me to see the real problem. Could you specify how you use this objects exactly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PhpStorm cannot figure out what type your `$this->cxn` field is. You can help by providing typehint via simple PHPDoc comment:

```
/** @var Database */
private $cxn;       //database object
```

Answer (score 11):

also this hint is helping PHPstorm to recognize the methods correctly

if you have code like this:

```
foreach( $myEntity as $entity ) {  
  $entity->myValidMethod();
}
```

just add this hint:

```
/* @var $entity \My\Name\Space\Path\MyEntity */
foreach( $myEntity as $entity ) {  
  $entity->myValidMethod();
}
```

thanks to http://mossco.co.uk/symfony-2/how-to-fix-method-not-found-in-class-orange-warning-in-phpstorm/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are visibility issues in the code. The PHP manual states:

```
Class methods may be defined as public, private, or protected. Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.
```

I think you might have two Database classes.  Similar issue was described in this topic:
[best way to call function from an extended class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295819/best-way-to-call-function-from-an-extended-class)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **close()** function you could try `function __destruct() {}` [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

The problem is in missing public/protected/private

Comment: The only problem here is the default visibility of a function in a class in php is public.

Answer (score 0):

you must just add "public" keyword  on method declaration in your database class IMHO

```
public function close()
```