# PHPStorm - Method not found in subject class

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting

I have a project that I'm working on and I just switched over to PHPStorm because it's starting to get big and I need some refactoring tools. I noticed that since variables aren't declared as types (like they are in Java) PHPStorm doesn't know where to look for method calls on variable names sometimes. Here's my code.

```
<?php

require_once "autoloader.php";


class User {

    private $userID;
    private $email;
    private $encryptedPassword;
    private $userDBWriter;
    private $company;
    private $companyInfoChangeRequest;
    private $admin;
    private $accountIsActive;
    private $dealTracker;
    private $changeRequestPending;

    function __construct($email, $encryptedPassword) {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->encryptedPassword = $encryptedPassword;
        $this->userDBWriter = new UserDBWriter();
        $this->admin = false;
        $this->dealTracker = new DealTracker($this);
    }

    public function addUserToDB() {
        $this->userDBWriter->addUserToDB($this);
    }

    public function setUserAsAdmin($adminStatus) {
        $this->admin = (bool) $adminStatus;
    }

    public function userAccountActiveStatus($accountStatus) {
        $this->accountIsActive = (bool) $accountStatus;
    }

    public function setUserID($userID) {
        $this->userID = $userID;
    }

    public function getUserID() {
        return $this->userID;
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function isAdmin() {
        return $this->admin;
    }

    public function isAccountActive() {
        return $this->accountIsActive;
    }

    public function getEncryptedPassword() {
        return $this->encryptedPassword;
    }

    public function toArray() {
        $userArray = array(
            "id"=>$this->userID,
            "email"=>$this->email,
            "company_name"=>$this->getCompanyName(),
            "business_type"=>$this->getBusinessType(),
            "company_phone"=>$this->getCompanyPhone(),
            "company_street"=>$this->getCompanyStreet(),
            "company_city"=>$this->getCompanyCity(),
            "company_zip"=>$this->getCompanyZip(),
            "monday_hours"=>$this->getMondayHours(),
            "tuesday_hours"=>$this->getTuesdayHours(),
            "wednesday_hours"=>$this->getWednesdayHours(),
            "thursday_hours"=>$this->getThursdayHours(),
            "friday_hours"=>$this->getFridayHours(),
            "saturday_hours"=>$this->getSaturdayHours(),
            "sunday_hours"=>$this->getSundayHours(),
            "store_image_path"=>$this->getStoreImagePath(),
            "shop_description"=>$this->getShopDescription(),
            "deals"=>$this->dealTracker->dealsToArray()
            );
        return $userArray;  
    }

    public function addCompany(Company $company) {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

        public function getCompanyName() {
            return $this->company->getCompanyName();
        }

        public function getBusinessType() {
            return $this->company->getBusinessType();
        }

        public function getCompanyPhone() {
            return $this->company->getCompanyPhone();
        }

        public function getCompanyStreet() {
            return $this->company->getCompanyStreet();
        }

        public function getCompanyCity() {
            return $this->company->getCompanyCity();
        }

        public function getCompanyState() {
            return $this->company->getCompanyState();
        }

        public function getCompanyZip() {
            return $this->company->getCompanyZip();
        }

        public function getMondayHours() {
            return $this->company->getMondayHours();
        }

        public function getTuesdayHours() {
            return $this->company->getTuesdayHours();
        }

        public function getWednesdayHours() {
            return $this->company->getWednesdayHours();
        }

        public function getThursdayHours() {
            return $this->company->getThursdayHours();
        }

        public function getFridayHours() {
            return $this->company->getFridayHours();
        }

        public function getSaturdayHours() {
            return $this->company->getSaturdayHours();
        }

        public function getSundayHours() {
            return $this->company->getSundayHours();
        }

        public function getStoreImagePath() {
            return $this->company->getStoreImagePath();
        }

        public function getShopDescription() {
            return $this->company->getShopDescription();
        }

        public function isBusinessVerified() {
            return $this->company->getVerifiedBusiness();
        }

    public function setCompanyInfoChangeRequest($company) {
        $this->companyInfoChangeRequest = $company;
    }

    public function submitCompanyInfoChangeRequest($company) {
        $this->companyInfoChangeRequest = new CompanyInfoChangeRequest($this, $company);
        $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->submitCompanyInfoChangeRequest();
    }

    public function cancelCompanyInfoChangeRequest() {
        if ($this->changeRequestPending) {
            $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->cancelRequest();
        }
    }

    public function isCompanyChangeRequestPending() {
        return $this->changeRequestPending;
    }

    public function approveCompanyInfoChangeRequest($company) {
        $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->approveCompanyInfoChangeRequest($this);
    }

    public function setChangeRequestPending($isPending) {
        $this->changeRequestPending = (bool) $isPending;
    }
        public function getChangeRequestCompanyName() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getCompanyName();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestBusinessType() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getBusinessType();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestCompanyPhone() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getCompanyPhone();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestCompanyStreet() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getCompanyStreet();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestCompanyCity() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getCompanyCity();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestCompanyState() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getCompanyState();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestCompanyZip() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getCompanyZip();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestMondayHours() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getMondayHours();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestTuesdayHours() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getTuesdayHours();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestWednesdayHours() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getWednesdayHours();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestThursdayHours() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getThursdayHours();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestFridayHours() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getFridayHours();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestSaturdayHours() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getSaturdayHours();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestSundayHours() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getSundayHours();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestStoreImagePath() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getStoreImagePath();
        }

        public function getChangeRequestShopDescription() {
            return $this->companyInfoChangeRequest->getShopDescription();
        }

}
```

Some of the methods with the warning `"Method not found in class..."` are `getCompanyName()` `getBusinessType()` `getCompanyPhone()` and any other method that calls a method on `$this->company` or `$this->companyInfoChangeRequest`.

I know why this is happening. It's because PHPStorm doesn't know what the variable is an instance of. I noticed here [Method not found in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787607/method-not-found-in-class) they used a PHPDoc comment to type hint the variable type so PHPStorm knows where to look. **I would like a "non-comment" solution** because if I come across a comment in the future I'm liable to delete it. Sorry about the long class. I'm importing the project into PHPStorm so I can start to do some refactoring. Thanks.

Comment: *" I would like a "non-comment" solution because if I come across a comment in the future **I'm liable to delete it**."* Why "delete it"? What is wrong with PHPDoc comments? have you seen any of the modern frameworks/libraries, how they use PHPDoc?

Comment: Why do I delete comments? Because they clutter up the code. You can make the argument for documentation and if it's done right then that's great. If the comment were to be removed then the refactoring tools would break. I'd rather rely on code than a comment.

Comment: Obviously, the choice is completely yours (think about other users/devs who will use the code after you wondering what this code does and what these fields/methods do). I'll just leave it here, in case if you will be interesting/have not seen it yet. http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely take a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer:

---

Add `$this->company = new Company;` to your `__construct` function.  Now, phpStorm knows exactly what functions `$this->company` has.

### Explanation:

---

This might make things very complicated for your application, because it will call `Company::__construct` from within the `User::__construct` -- effectively doubling its processing and memory payload because from what I can see, an instance of `Company` already exists.  Maybe you won't need to create an instance of Company outside of the `User` class any longer?

Also, since you've already got a `$company` object in memory, it seems more practical to normalize your classes and put (and use) all "Company" functionality in the "Company" class, and limit the "User" class to "User" functionality, and simply use `$company->getCompanyName()` to get that information, instead of the round-robin `$user->getCompanyName()` function - which merely calls `$company->getCompanyName()` anyways.

Give it a try, see what you think?

Comment: Ok cool, that makes sense. I see your point with the company. The thing with the company is that a company belongs to a user. Which is why other parts of the system would ask the user for their company name. Should I be doing it that way?

Comment: The bigger a project gets, the more compartmentalized (in classes) you will want related data and functions.  Weird errors like _"Method 'x' not found in class 'y'..."_ help you write good code; now you can see why!  :)  To answer your comment-question regarding the ownership of a **company** by a **user**, consider a scenario where perhaps a user owns more than one company, and with that frame of reference, study one-to-many relationships in database theory:  [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561)

Comment: One warning about the code in my answer.  As-is, there will be **two** instances of Company floating around; one in the global scope, and one within the instance of User.  Beware that changes made to the one copy will not be reflected in the values of the other!

Comment: I'm giving it some thought. It did actually occur to me that later on we might want more than 1 company per user. I'm definitely not copying, pasting, and forgetting about it. I think the one-to-many relationship is what I'm going to go with, but we'll see. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

For completeness sake, and to offer SO users with a viable alternative, I prefer **a comments based solution** that uses PHPdocs to do this, so in your instance i would do :

```
/**
*   @var Company 
*/
private $company.
```

you get the benefit of well documented classes, with meaningful info when you are editing code that uses the class in question. I put regularly phpdocs on vars, constructor methods and most public business methods. Doing it systematically is a small price to pay for the benefits you will reap over time with a large code base and PHPStorm.

find the details at [PHPDoc.org](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html)

Comment: BY FAR a superior solution to burning processing power at runtime!

Comment: See https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html - note that I had to do something more like `@var $company Company`

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who face with this issue, if the file length is large (>5000 lines of code), the code analysis stops working prior to version 2021.1.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31569?_ga=2.242515972.704716569.1621073600-273941255.1612557945

If you're using previous versions, only solution seems to refactor code to decrease code length.