# PhpStorm & Yii2 shows "method insert not found in.."

Tags: yii2, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have several cases in Yii2 where the code analysis of PhpStorm will show that it can not find a method, even if these methods are Yii2 own methods.

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('customer');
$collection->insert(['name' => 'John Smith', 'status' => 1]);
```

This is a standard example from the Yii2 documentation for mongoDB. But it shows this error:

> Method 'insert' not found in (more...)

Please note that it does not state anything after " ... in ..." so I think it does not know at all which class is used at all.

Is there something I tell PhpStorm which class this is? Like via the PHPDoc or something?

Comment: have you opened this file inside of a project? or a standalone file

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787607/method-not-found-in-class) post if it helps

Comment: Are you using Yii2 plugin? Please check https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9388-yii2-support & https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/865/configuring-phpstorm-ide-for-yii-2

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: Your link to the post was correct. I will update this thread with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The right hint came from  Muhammad Omer Aslam in the comments to the original question.

I just needed to add this lphpDoc line just before the use of the insert.

```
 /* @var $collection \Yii\MongoDb\Collection */
```

Then it will recognise the class used and throws no errors.

Thanks everybody for helping.

Comment: Small note: PHPDoc comment starts with `/**` (two asterisks). What you have there is an ordinary PHP comment. Correct order is `/** @var TYPE $variable */`. PhpStorm will handle all 4 variations .. but another IDE/editor may not. So better use "official" way if possible.

Comment: You should have closed the question by marking as a duplicate for the same post i mentioned rather than adding the answer, thats why i didnt posted the answer and wanted you to have a look first if its the same case. Take care & Happy New Year.

Comment: @LazyOne This syntax is called "vardoc" (or "vdoc") and it is commonly used (and supported) for typehints. Using PHPDoc syntax for everything may break PHPDoc rules, so using vardoc may be better option for simple typehints.